# WPF Datagrid does not show entries

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, sqlite, datagrid

Im new to WPF and C# so please dont rip my head of if i should have done something stupid^^
Im trying to show some data from a SQLite Database file by using a DataGrid. I already installed the relevant package from the SQLite page that includes the VisualStudios designer components. I added the Databasefile as a datasource in Visual Studios which worked pretty good. If i open the Database with the datapreview function it shows my Data the way it should.

My Problem is that even tho i boundet the Datasource as shown on the MSDN page it still isnt showing any Entries, but it sucessfully created all Colums.

Heres my XAML Code:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:WorkDataSet x:Key="WorkDataSet"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="personalViewSource" Source="{Binding Personal, Source={StaticResource WorkDataSet}}"/>
```

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource personalViewSource}">
    <Label Content="Personal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="personalDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,100,10,10" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="iDColumn" Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="stationColumn" Binding="{Binding Station}" Header="Station" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="_ACD_IDColumn" Binding="{Binding ACD-ID}" Header="ACD-ID" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="bild1Column" Header="Bild 1" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Bild1}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="bild2Column" Header="Bild 2" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Bild2}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="visitColumn" Header="Visit" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Visit, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

as far as is understood this it should not require any further C# code cause everything should be set automaticly by Visual Studios.

I know there are a view Questions like this arround here but non of these use SQLite in the way i do...

Comment: Did you check if there is any messages in the output window of visual studio!

Comment: Show your WorkDataSet code